# GKE application logs (pods/container/deployments) not visible in GCP Cloud Logging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I've set up a GKE Autopilot cluster with off-the-shelf configuration [terraform example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/using_gke_with_terraform). The cluster came up with no issues with right configuration and I am able to deploy jobs as well.

**Problem:**
I can see cluster wide logs but for some reason I am not able to see job/containers logs anywhere in cloud logging. I am not able to connect to the individual containers as well.

Nature of the cluster -

1. Private Cluster (VPC Native)
2. The project in which the cluster **is deployed is in vpc sc perimeter**, the apis are whitelisted.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are your jobs writing logs to stdout / sidère ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem is two fold -

1. GKE Autopilot Nodepool uses default GCE SA which in my case is deleted.
2. You cannot assign a SA to a nodepool which is already created, so
   a. Destroy the cluster
   b. Create a SA and make it a default GCE SA.
   c. Re create the cluster
   d. Make sure the above SA has logging/monitoring permissions.

Comment: Hi, @anilit99. Same problem here. Could you please elaborate your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just as information here is the link to the official documentation for the [Autopilot](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview) feature.